# Should a sign up for two different accounts be split into two pages?

Tags: workflow, signup-signon, page, signup

Let's say there is a sign up for merchant and customers. Is it okay if I make the sign up page for the both of them on one page? I added an image here as an example. The sign up is for merchants and the log in is for customers. [image: this is the illustration]

Comment: Related: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/97803/user-login-and-signup-for-app-with-multiple-but-separate-roles

Comment: "The sign up is for merchants and the log in is for customers." - you mean it is currently implemented this way? It seems confusing this way and doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Well keep a single form for both of them just differ them on the basis of type like a dropdown with merchant or customer option on sign up. And while signing in, maybe a checkbox maybe which says want to login as a merchant. Depends which one do you want to show as default.

Secondly, apart from this, Don't just give placeholders for input fields because while typing they would disappear. From UX perspective, it is better if you give label on top of the field for better readability.

Comment: so in conclusion, is it better to split the pages? i'm sorry i really confuse what is more effective:(

Comment: You can split as well to have different pages altogether for both but the user can be customer or merchant both at the same time, right? Having separate pages means they know they are on specific url (customer or merchant). Having both on single page allows them to be able to just go to single url and switch /select the relevant role and log in.

Comment: "From UX perspective, it is better if you give label on top of the field for better readability" - what is your evidence for that? Placeholders in input fields make the form seem less cluttered and therefore easier to fill. Judging from personal experience I have not noticed any problem with placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

No, it should not be a different form. let them signup and just ask the primary role in the form itself. and if it is something where a single user can play different roles then there should be option to switch roles after the login.